# ExtJS 5.0 - moving components in overrides

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

We have code from a third party which we aren't allowed to modify directly, can use only overrides.

On one of the forms, a client would be better served by changing the order of some of the components. I can do this within DOM, but that approach is quite fragile and can cause problems in the framework. I've looked into `moveBefore` and `moveAfter` in `Ext.container.Container` but frankly, they don't work.

I'm looking for 1) the best place to override, e.g. the view's `constructor`, or the view's `initComponent`, or maybe the view controller's overrides, etc. and 2) if there are any **reliable** ExtJS methods to move components around.

E.g. `initComponent` override in `XYView.js`

```
initComponent: function () {
    this.callParent([]);
    // Get the components, X and Y, error checking omitted
    var X = this.query('*[itemId=X]')[0];
    var Y = this.query('*[itemId=Y]')[0];
    // Move X before Y
    // This doesn't work properly -- the layout is messed up!
    this.insertBefore(X, Y);
}
```

To reiterate, I would prefer to do this within ExtJS and avoid DOM manipulations if at all possible.

Comment: if you manipulate the DOM directly how do you think that ExtJS will know about this and know to re-render the component? To put it bluntly **If you are directly manipulating the DOM and using ExtJS you are doing it wrong!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose the right parent to call `moveBefore`. I've revised your code by finding the parents of X and Y, using parentX to remove X, then parentY to move X next to Y:

```
initComponent: function () {
    this.callParent([]);
    // Get the components, X and Y, error checking omitted
    var X = this.query('*[itemId=X]')[0];
    var Y = this.query('*[itemId=Y]')[0];
    // Move X before Y
    // Revised code follows
    // Get direct parents
    var parentOfX = X.findParentBy(function (container, me) {return !(container == me);});
    var parentOfY = Y.findParentBy(function (container, me) {return !(container == me);});
    // Remove first to be safe, don't autodestroy
    X = parentOfX.remove(X, false);
    // Reposition under the correct parent
    parentOfY.moveBefore(X, Y);
}
```

I've tested as an `initComponent` override and it seems to work okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove components from containers and insert them again. The syntax is

```
.remove( component, autoDestroy ) : Ext.Component
```

where autoDestroy === false to keep the component alive. Then use

```
.insert( index, component ) : Ext.Component
```

If you do that in `initComponent` you are probably doing it wrong, because you still have access to the config objects and should manipulate them directly.

For performance reasons suspend layouts for multiple inserts: `.suspendLayouts()` (globally or per container).

Use the docs, they are very good: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Container

PS: grid rows are manipulated via the store, css and custom renderers, don't touch the dom directly.

**UPDATE**
You will get the best performance by manipulating your configs in the constructor as there is less work to do for the framework. `initComponent` is actually called in a components constructor, so it's pretty much the same.

In the constructor you get the configs like this:

```
constructor: function(config) {
//...
}
```

In initComponent the configs are already part of the object. Just beware of the order when calling the parent via `callParent`. Find your child items by iterating the items-property, e.g. via `Ext.Array.findBy` and look for the itemId. Move items using javascript native methods such as `Array.splice()`.

If performance doesn't matter move your components around at a later stage, e.g. in the `afterrender` event. Here you can use extjs methods to find and move components, e.g. `down()` `remove()` `insert()`.

Comment: Added details to OP. I don't think I can modify `config`. If `initComponent` is not a good place to override, can you suggest a better one? Also if the source is modified a lot, using indices is kind of fragile. I tried `moveBefore` and `moveAfter` but it moves them in completely unexpected places, not at all logical, like several levels up.

Comment: See update. You have to think about nested containers etc yourself in case you move components to a higher component hierarchy level. In that case it would be easier to move instantiated components. I don't think you can do that in initComponent, but could be wrong. Just try it.